# How can i transfer variable from a file to another

Tags: android, android-intent, if-statement

I have a problem with my app. I am trying to transfer an integer from a activity using this code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Lesson.class); 
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Example1.class);

            switch(position){                                                     
                case 0: {intent.putExtra("Title", l1);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}                   
                case 1: {intent.putExtra("Title", l2);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}                   
                case 2: {intent.putExtra("Title", l3);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}                   
                case 3: {intent.putExtra("Title", l4);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}                   
                case 4: {intent.putExtra("Title", l5);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}                   
                case 5: {intent.putExtra("Title", l6);intent1.putExtra("check_cat", position);break;}
```

The first intent works but the second one is not working. I dont receive any data. Here is the code where I process the informations:

```
    final int[] pos_categ = new int[1];
    pos_categ[0] = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("check_cat");
```

Then I try to use it as a condition for an "if statement":

```
if (pos_categ[0]==1){
        title[0] = lessons_titles[position[0]];
        eng[0] = eng_version[position[0]];
        dan[0] = dan_version[position[0]].toLowerCase();
    }
    if (pos_categ[0]==2){
        title[0] = lessons_titles2[position[0]];
        eng[0] = eng_version2[position[0]];
        dan[0] = dan_version2[position[0]].toLowerCase();
    }
    if (pos_categ[0]==3){
        title[0] = lessons_titles3[position[0]];
        eng[0] = eng_version3[position[0]];
        dan[0] = dan_version3[position[0]].toLowerCase();
    }...
```

I dont get any errors but from the app is not going through the if statement because the variable pos_categ[0] doesn't have any value... can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: But why two `Intent`s? Are you sending two `Intent`s to one `Activity`? (it  is actually impossible)

Comment: i send to two different activities.(Lesson.class and Example1.class)

Comment: In your post which code snippet belongs to which?

Comment: The first code belongs to the activity from where I send data and the others to the one where I receive.

Comment: **"i send to two different activities."** : You can't start two activities at the same time. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to have two conditions in my example1.class activity. one that is the main activity and one that is the Lesson.class activity. so from the main activity I want to sent to the Example1.class the variable check_cat.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do two things
first check every time that their is an intent.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra("check_cat"))
{
// your code
}
```

second you need to take the int as regular int.

```
 final int pos_categ = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("check_cat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final int[] post_categ = new int[] {getIntent().getExtras().getInt("check_cat")};
```

Or better still:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int pos_categ = 0;
if(intent.hasExtra("check_cat")) {
   pos_categ = intent.getExtras().getInt("check_cat");
}
```